# on discord, how do you show/hide the list of users in a room?

Tags: discord

on discord, how do you show/hide the list of users in a room?

for example

I used to see a list in discord on the side showing all the users in the room.. but I don't see it anymore.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button is in the top right of the screen, showing as 2 people:

[image]